# How to use Django's session engine with subdomains?

Tags: python, django, django-sessions

I need to access a user's `sessionid` from within a subdomain on my site, so I can enable "single sign-on", but I can't seem to get it to work, despite changing `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = '.localtest'` in my settings.

### MRE

You need to modify `/etc/hosts` to include `localtest` if you want to reproduce the error.  Also **note** that this is only tested on macOS, so YMMV.

urls.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth import views
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.urls import path

@login_required
def home_view(request):
    raise Exception('user was logged in')

urlpatterns = [
    path('login', views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('home', home_view, name='home'),
]
```

settings.py:

```
BASE_DOMAIN = 'localtest'
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = '.' + BASE_DOMAIN
LOGIN_URL = '/login'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/home'
```

When I attempt to log a user in via the builtin `LoginView`, the login is successful, and the user is redirected to `/home` (which is on the same domain as the login).  After the login redirect, the user's session gets dropped, and the `login_required` triggers, sending the user back to the login page.

Why is this happening?  Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

If you want to reproduce this on your machine, here is a [repo](https://github.com/Lord-Elrond/django_session_bug). The database has a test user set with the username `root` and password `root`